# How to remove the headers in the table of contents in memoir class?

Tags: header-footer, memoir

In the project I was making with the `memoir` class, I made a page style named **CCSL** derived from `plain` pagestyle.

```
\documentclass[extrafontsizes,11pt,twocolumn,openany,openbib]{memoir}
\copypagestyle{CCSL}{plain}
\makeevenhead{plain}{\thepage}{}{\bfseries\leftmark}
\makeoddhead{plain}{\bfseries DOCUMENT TITLE}{}{\thepage}
\makeevenfoot{plain}{}{}{}
\makeoddfoot{plain}{}{}{}

\begin{document}
\onecolumn
\pagestyle{empty}{\color{white}a}
\par\vspace{0.35\textheight}
{\centering\noindent{\scshape\HUGE\textbf{DOCUMENT TITLE}}\linebreak
\large{SOME TEXT}\\
\large{SOME TEXT}
\par\vspace{3\baselineskip}
\noindent\LARGE\bfseries {SOME TEXT}\\}
\clearpage
\tableofcontents
\twocolumn

\pagestyle{CCSL}
\chapter*[SOME CHAPTER]{SOME CHAPTER}
.
.
.
\end{document}
```

As you can see from my code, I used the `empty` pagestyle for the self-made title page and the table of contents page, and then I applied the `CCSL` pagestyle to the rest of the document. However, the setting of `empty` pagestyle only worked to the self-made title page and not with the ToC page, and weirdly, it adapted the pagestyle that was set after `\tableofcontents`. I tried using `\thispagestyle{empty}` for the ToC page but it did nothing. I also tried putting `\pagestyle{empty}` immediately before the `\tableofcontents`, but it had the same effect.

Answer (score 1):

You could redefine memoir's `\aftertoctitle` macro as follows:

```
\renewcommand{\aftertoctitle}{%
   \thispagestyle{empty}
   \afterchaptertitle}
```

Repeat, if needed, for `\afterloftitle` and `\afterlottitle`.

See also p. 148 of the [memoir user guide](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/memoir/memman.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your preamble:

```
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\thispagestyle{empty}}
```

Aside: why did you use `{\color{white}a}`?

This works for me:

```
\documentclass[extrafontsizes,11pt,twocolumn,openany,openbib]{memoir}
\copypagestyle{CCSL}{plain}
\makeevenhead{plain}{\thepage}{}{\bfseries\leftmark}
\makeoddhead{plain}{\bfseries DOCUMENT TITLE}{}{\thepage}
\makeevenfoot{plain}{}{}{}
\makeoddfoot{plain}{}{}{}

\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\thispagestyle{empty}}

\begin{document}
\onecolumn
\pagestyle{empty}
\par\vspace{0.35\textheight}
{\centering\noindent{\scshape\HUGE\textbf{DOCUMENT TITLE}}\linebreak
\large{SOME TEXT}\\
\large{SOME TEXT}
\par\vspace{3\baselineskip}
\noindent\LARGE\bfseries {SOME TEXT}\\}
\clearpage
\tableofcontents
\twocolumn

\pagestyle{CCSL}
\chapter*[SOME CHAPTER]{SOME CHAPTER}

\end{document}
```

Comment: To a casual observer, the difference from Acnologia's MWE is not obvious. Perhaps you could add a small description of what you changed.

Comment: I've edited my answer.

Comment: @SLx64 - Thanks for the answer! I did not thought of the `\addtocontents` command! For the other question, I used `{\color{white}a}` to center the document title and the following texts, because I found out that without a preceding text, all the spaces I try to implement will not take into effect. As a follow-up question, can I ask why is it that the ToC is not affected by the pagestyle I had set?